# Hotspot keeps disconnecting/connecting if smartphone too close to laptop

Tags: connection-issues, wifi-hotspot, mobile-network

I have a Windows 11 laptop and everything was fine before. But today, I noticed my laptop disconnects from my mobile hotspot if it's too close.

I have to keep the smartphone outside the room for it to work normally. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You probably can't do anything about it and the problem is unlikely to be in your smartphone. It can be some issue related to WiFi drivers in the laptop.

Comment: Please provide details of both devices.  It could just be noise.  I don't have a problem with mine.

Comment: It got fixed on its own. I have no idea what had happened